# Make table in HTML using rowspan and colspan

Tags: html

I want to make table in HTML.

```
-------------------------------
|Id | Name | Contact Number   |
|          |------------------
|          |Mobile  |Landline |
------------------------------
|1  |joy   |9045454 |04-54225 |
-------------------------------
```

What should I do?

Comment: "what should i do" what do you think you should do?

Comment: You should learn basic html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that, in this case, is just about colspan: you have 4 cols in total, so the code may looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Id</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td colspan="2">Contact Number</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
        <td>Mobile</td>
        <td>Landline</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Joy</td>
        <td>9045454</td>
        <td>04-54225</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Well, add some styles and you get it!

Answer (score 2):

```
<table border="border">
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">Id</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Name</th>
            <th colspan="2">Contact no</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <th>Mobile</th>
            <th>Landline</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>joy</td>
            <td>9045454</td>
            <td>04-54225</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

****Hope this helps you****